# Soft reset shell script not working properly

Tags: pi-2, reset, powershell

Using the directions on this [webpage](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/add-reset-switch-raspberry-pi/), I downloaded raspi_gpio_actions.sh.

I then created a script directory, "scripts" in /home/pi and placed the shell script there. I ran these commands: `sudo chmod 755 raspi_gpio_actions.sh` and `sudo ./raspi_gpio_actions.sh`.

I then added this line to `/etc/crontab`:

```
@reboot        root    /home/user/scripts/raspi_gpio_actions.sh
```

saved and closed the file, and rebooted my Raspberry Pi 2. I placed a jumper across the pins referenced in the shell script as 5 and 6 (and pin 3 and the ground pin above in the diagram below). During earlier edits of this post, I was not able to get it to shutdown, but now I can at times.

The script only sometimes shuts down the Raspberry Pi, when I run the script manually as root. It only does this when the jumper is plugged into both pins *before* the program runs, and it will shutdown. But if I plug in the jumper across the pins *after* the program is running, it will not shutdown.

This is the shell script (which has not changed since 2013, as of the time of the post.)

```
#! /bin/bash

 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #  
#                                                                             #     
# This script configures which GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi will be          #
# available and in which direction (read or write). It also takes some        #
# actions if someone interacts with the selected pins.                        #
#                                                                             #
# More info about the GPIO: http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals       #
#                                                                             #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#                                                                             #
# -Raspberry Pi Rev2. GPIO layout:                                            #
#                                                                             #
#           2  4  6  8  10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26    _R_C_A_                 #
#           |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |     |______|                #
#           --------------------------------------                            #
#           |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |                             #
#    _      1  3  5  7  9  11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25                            #
#   | |                                                                       #
#   | | SD Card                                                               #
#   | |                                                                       #
#   |_|                                                                       #
#                                                                             #
#   P1-01: 3.3v       P1-10: GPIO15     P1-20: GND                            #
#   P1-02: 5.0v       P1-11: GPIO17     P1-21: GPIO9                          #
#   P1-03: GPIO2      P1-12: GPIO18     P1-22: GPIO25                         #
#   P1-04: 5.0v       P1-13: GPIO27     P1-23: GPIO11                         #
#   P1-05: GPIO3      P1-14: GND        P1-24: GPIO8                          #
#   P1-06: GND        P1-15: GPIO22     P1-25: GND                            #
#   P1-07: GPIO4      P1-16: GPIO23     P1-26: GPIO7                          #
#   P1-08: GPIO14     P1-17: 3.3v                                             #
#   P1-09: GND        P1-18: GPIO24                                           #
#                     P1-19: GPIO10                                           #
#                                                                             #
# NOTE: Pins GPIO2 and GPIO3 have a 1K8 pull up resistor, which means that    # 
# you can short cirtuit them directly to ground and you'll get a 1 as a non   #
# connected value (iddle) and a 0 as a connected value (short circuit to GND) #
# when reading them.                                                          #
#                                                                             #
#                                                                             #
#  by g0to                                                                    #
#                                                                             #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #  


if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "Error: This script must be run as root" >&2
   exit 1
fi

SHUTDOWN_PIN="3"
#DHCP_ON_PIN="2"

echo "$SHUTDOWN_PIN" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio"$SHUTDOWN_PIN"/direction
#echo "$DHCP_ON_PIN" > /sys/class/gpio/export
#echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio"$DHCP_ON_PIN"/direction

while ( true )
do
    # check if the pin is connected to GND and, if so, halt the system
    if [ $(</sys/class/gpio/gpio"$SHUTDOWN_PIN"/value) == 0 ]
    then
        echo "$SHUTDOWN_PIN" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
        shutdown -h now "System halted by a GPIO action"
#   elif [ $(</sys/class/gpio/gpio"$DHCP_ON_PIN"/value) == 0 ]
#   then
#       dhclient eth0
    fi

    sleep 60
done
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like part of my problem is I am not waiting long enough!

Comment: My real problem was I forgot to add a newline to the end of the last line! So now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to check and debug crontab.

First run the command:

```
ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
```

If it returns something like this

```
root       480     1  0 23:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

You are good to go. Otherwise restart.

```
/sbin/service cron start
```

Also check to make sure last line has a newline!

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it